# Affrication des dentales au Québec

Tags: prononciation, québec, affrication

Il y a assez généralement au Québec<sup>1</sup> affrication des consonnes dentales, T et D, lorsqu’elles sont suivies des sons I ou U :

- dit /di/, réalisé [d͡zi]
- du /dy/, réalisé [d͡zy]
- poutine /putin/, réalisé [put͡sɪn]
- tiers /tjɛʁ/, réalisé [t͡sjɛʁ]
- tuile /tɥil/, réalisé [t͡sɥɪl]

Existe-t-il des exceptions, des cas où même ceux, ou une partie non-négligeable de ceux qui utilisent habituellement cette manière de s’exprimer ne le feront jamais pour certains mots en particulier ?

---

<sub>J’ai personnellement cette manière de prononcer, et je connais certaines exceptions à mon vocabulaire, mais le tout semble très peu documenté, contrairement à l’affrication, assez communément traitée en long et en large lorsqu’il s’agit du français parlé au Québec. Je suis donc curieux de voir si ma manière d’avoir des exception est elle-même une exception, ou si l’on saura trouver une documentation pertinente à ce sujet.</sub>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>On notera les notables exceptions de la Gaspésie et des îles de la Madeleine, ainsi que la version acadienne en général du français, présente hors-Québec dans les provinces maritimes du Canada, où ce phénomène d’affrication est généralement absent ou fort estompé.</sub>

Comment: Je ne sais pas si cette question passera, mais ça coûte bien peu d’essayer. Désolé si j’ai fait erreur.

Comment: J'avais vu passer cela : https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01147769/document (zappez direct p28) document qui m'avait semblé à l'époque original (lier l'**assibilation** à la laison), fondé sur des données récentes et assez critique vis-à-vis d'autres études reconnues. Mais, n'y connaissant rien... j'avais juste lu avec intérêt et curiosité. Alors peut-être ne vous apprendra-t-il rien du tout.

Comment: J'ai été obligé d'écouter [tuile](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tuile) sur Wiktionnaire pour comprendre comment ça pouvait être prononcé autrement... je suis incapable de prononcer _tu_ sans qu'on entende le _s_, donc même si j'essaye de dire _tu-il_ comme ce que j'entends dans l'audio, ça donne toujours de l'affrication. Avec beaucoup d'effort de la bouche et en levant la tête je réussis presque mais ça se rapproche de quand je siffle hahah. Merci !

Answer (score 1):

N'étant pas spécialiste, je tente une réponse.

Je me rappelle avoir déjà lu quelque part que l'origine de cette façon de parler remonterait aux premiers colons qui, parce qu'ils avaient si froid lors des hivers, en sont venus à parler avec les dents serrées. Les hivers auront été suffisamment longs pour forger la parlure! Je peine malheureusement à retrouver des références sur ceci mais n'importe qui ayant déjà attendu l'autobus par -20° celsius en jasant avec d'autres sait que cette théorie est plausible!

Je dirais donc qu'il n'y a aucune exception parce que l'affrication se fait dès que les sons *tu*, *du*, *ti*, *di* sont prononcés, peu importe le mot ou les lettres qui suivent.

Comment: Que penser des Européens francophones qui viennent s'installer au Canada? J'en ai connu aux Territoires du Nord-Ouest qui n'affriquaient pas du tout après vingt ans là-bas...

Comment: Les chaumières des premiers colons n'ont rien à voir avec nos maisons modernes qui sont isolées et bien chauffées. Ils ont gelé pendant 6 mois à toutes les heures, ce qui n'est pas le cas des nouveaux arrivants d'aujourd'hui.

Comment: J'ai aussi gelé des semaines dans des tentes dans l'Arctique, y causant anglais sans affriquer, et retournant à l'affrication en français une fois de retour au chaud à la maison. Les inuits n'affriquent pas. Beaucoup de vague, d'imprécis et de présomptions ici...

Comment: Je ne fais que relater une théorie que je trouvais intéressante, je n'affirme rien. Par ailleurs et pour faire suite au dernier commentaire, les autochtones et les inuits n'ont pas eu à s'adapter étant ici, au froid, depuis longtemps. Mais bien sûr, tout ceci n'est que spéculation.

Comment: Je suis effectivement québécois et je parle de cette façon d'où mon intérêt pour cette question et pour la théorie que je rapporte avoir lue. Quant à des exceptions, je ne vois pas dans quel contexte je les prononcerais autrement.

Comment: Merci! J'ai moi-même passé beaucoup de temps à ignorer que je me traînais ces exceptions, et ce n'est qu'il y a quelques années que je les ai remarquées. Pire encore, j'ai passé les dix-huit premières années de ma vie à ne même pas savoir que je prononçais pas **tu** mais **tsu** (ou **dzi**, etc.). Ma question était donc un peu, si l'information officielle fait défaut, une invitation pour les gens de rechercher sur eux-même et leur entourage ces potentielles exceptions... mais ça prend de l'attention. Et peut-être suis-je aussi une exception?

Comment: Par ailleurs, n'hésitez surtout pas, si vous retrouvez des sources, à les intégrer à votre réponse. J'avais moi aussi déjà entendu cette théorie, mais elle ne m'avait pas semblé résister à mes observations subséquentes et je l'avais mise de côté, sans autre état d'âme. Mais il y a peut-être, malgré tout, un peu de vrai dedans. Il serait intéressant de voir si de nouvelles observations peuvent la rendre crédible. Merci encore.

Comment: Oui. Je vais certainement rechercher des références et les ajouterai le cas échéant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87853/discussion-between-montee-de-lait-and-brac).