À la recherche d'une /i/ perdue
Selon cet article Wikipedia et d'autres sources, il n'existe dans la phonétique française
qu'un seul (allo)phone pour le phonème /i/, à savoir le [i] de l'API.
Mais parfois j'entends un autre allophone, plus fermé, le plus souvent à la fin de certains mots.
Des examples enregistrés que j'ai trouvé pour le moment:

Dans cette vidéo, le mot <partie> à la minute 0:38 versus par example le mot <exercices>.
Dans cette autre vidéo, le mot <aujourd'hui> (0:12) en contrast avec <compliqué> (0:19).
Dans cette autre video, le /i/ en <phonétique> par opposition au /i/ de <existe> (exemple pas trop marqué).
Dans la même vidéo, le mot <dire> à la minute 0:20.

Pour essayer d'être un peu plus précis, j'entends une différence de timbre.
J'entends un son plus complexe, plus fermé ou rétracté, avec plus d'harmoniques, que le son [i] auquel je suis habitué (du catalan, espagnol, et italien, par example, et aussi en français dans les autres cas), ce dernier étant plus pur, plus simple.
C'est un son que j'entends aussi en suédois, par exemple dans le mot <sil> (écouter ici).
Je l'entends aussi quand certains gens prononcent « bon appétit ».
Je sais prononcer une [i] normale, mais je ne sais pais reproduire cet autre son.
Donc c'est impossible que ce soient le même son.*
J'ai démandé aussi à un ami suédois, il entend la différence aussi.
Quelle est la différence phonétique exactement ? Je crois que c'est un [i] monté, donc la transcription serait [i◌̝] ?

* Let me be more precise: by "the difference existing", I mean that there is a continuum of sounds occurring in real French speech that cluster around two different points, this clustering being clear enough to justify the use of two "discrete" phones.

To my only semi-trained ear it sounds kind of like anticipating the [c]-like sound that often gets added to word-final /i/, but outside its usual context if it's in "phonétique", for example. Creating that friction would indeed mean raising the tongue slightly, closer to the roof of the mouth. But that's just my guess.

Cette personne prononce le [i] comme tous les français le prononcent, il n'y a pas de variantes régionales sur le son [î]. Ce qui peut troubler c'est que son intonation n'est pas du tout naturelle, ce qui peut peut-être déformer la perception de certains sons (parfois trop longs ou trop aigus). Elle sur-articule, ce qui fait qu'elle accentue parfois des syllabes qui ne devraient pas l'être (comme parfois la première syllabe de certains mots). L'intonation des phrases sonne faux aussi. Par contre la prononciation des sons en soi est correcte.

La prononciation du [i] français sur TV5 Monde.

Dans ma région, il y a deux "i".

@None Cet article, comme l'article de Wikipedia que je cite, parle seulement d'un type de son /i/ (front close unrounded vowel), puis il n'explique pas la difference.

@Frank Quelle est votre région ? Et la différence est-elle celle que j'ai mentionnée ci-dessus ?

C'est normal puisqu'il n'y a qu'une seule prononciation du [i] en français. La page que je cite est sérieuse (TV5Monde), c'est une référence, c'est pour montrer que la page de Wikipédia ne se trompe pas. Dans la vidéo que tu montres  les sons sont déformés (mais pas différents) à cause de l’intonation qui n'est pas naturelle.

Un de mes amis, d'origine Kabyle (francophone de naissance, parents bilingues), a tendance à intercaler un -j- entre une dentale accentuée et -i-, en tous cas c'est ce que j'entends: p. ex. id'jiot pour idiot, où l'apostrophe marque une accentuation. Je m'attendrais à entendre  ph'onét'chique au lieu de phonétique.

Quant à moi, je prononce différemment le i de existe du î de huître, et le a de bateau du â de gâteau.

Je ne crois pas que la différence soit ce que vous avez mentionné: OccItanIe ;-).

Peut être que si, parce que je me rappelle d'un habitant de Toulouse qui prononçait cette /i/ dans «bon appetit» par example. @None Oui, je comprends que les linguistes ont déterminé qu'il y a une seule /i/ en Français, et je le respecte, mais j'entends vraiment un son différent quelques fois (prôche à i de /sil/ en suédois), et pas seulement avec cet exemple; j'étais curieux de savoir si autres gens l'entendent aussi. C'est un son distincte de la [i] diaphane du italien ou espagnol par exemple, qui en théorie devrait être la même que la seule [i] française.

J'ai vécu plus de 20 ans à Toulouse et je peux t'assurer que le son [i] est prononcé de la même façon qu'à Paris (par exemple). Par contre certaines personnes (de plus en plus rare avec le jeunes générations) ont un accent très prononcé influencé avec l'occitan. En occitan les syllabes sont accentués différemment, ce qui change  la perception des sons.

@FrançoisJurain Dans huitre (ou huître) le [î]  est influencé par le [ɥ] qui le précède, c'est l'enchaînement qui modifie le son. Ce n'est pas du tout pareil que le [a] de pate et le [ɑ] de pâte qui sont effectivement deux sons différents (mais dont la différence s'est amenuisée au fil du temps pour avoir complètement disparue dans certains régions).

@None ce n'est pas ainsi que j'ai appris à prononcer. A l'école les instits m'expliquaient que c'est le ^ qui modifie la longueur du i. Pour moi, le î de huître est le même que celui de vous vîtes et de cuiller et il est plus long que celui de vitre.

@None en d'autres termes: la description du français que font les phonéticiens est (en partie) une fiction.

@FrançoisJurain J'ai cette impression aussi. Après tout, les phones sont un continuum, et les phonéticiens doivent décider quelles différences sont suffisamment relevants pour eux et quelles ne le sont pas, mais ça n'implique pas que ces différences n'existent pas.

J'espère que vous avez tous compris que je faisais une blague bidon sur les deux lettre "i" dans le mot "Occitanie", et pas du tout une remarque de phonétique?

@FrançoisJurain Oui, en théorie, mais moi je n'arrive pas à entendre de différence. C'est peut-être mon oreille, mais je n'y arrive pas.

@Frank Oh, je n'avais pas réalisé... Je suis un peu sot aujourd'hui :D

@FrançoisJurain La longueur ne change pas l'articulation du son [i], pas plus que la différence entre  le [a] et le [ɑ] soit une question de longueur, c'est une question d’articulation.   Si tu regardes de vieux dictionnaires qui ont encore l'ancienne orthographe tu peux voir que la transcription est [ɥitr(ə)], et je n'ai jamais entendu huitre prononcé différemment quelle que soit la région. (une huitre avec l'accent parisien sur Shtooka. Et je suis moi-même de la génération qui a appris et pratiqué l'ancienne orthographe et appris à parler avec.

@FrançoisJurain Non ce n'est pas une fiction, même partielle des phonéticiens. La phonétique est peut-être l'aspect le plus scientifique des sciences du langage, surtout avec l'apport des progrès en physique, les instruments de mesure sont de plus en plus performants. Cuiller a le même son [ɥi]  que huitre, ce n'est pas [i] tout seul come vitre ou vite.)  On ne peut pas comparer [i] entre deux consonnes et [i] dans le digramme [ɥi] (semi-voyelle + voyelle) où les deux sons représentent une seule et unique séquence.

Un phonème n'est pas un son unique mais une région de l'espace phonétique. Lorsqu'un phonème dans une langue s'étend sur deux phonèmes différents dans la langue maternelle d'une personne, celle-ci entend parfois tous les deux.

@Peter Oui, ça c'est ce que je voulais dire: je sais que il y a un seul phonème /i/, mais j'entends deux phones différents.

@None On ne peut pas comparer [i] entre deux consonnes et [i] dans le digramme c'est fort possible; ce qui est certain c'est qu'il n'est pas possible aujourd'hui de changer la manière dont la prononciation du français me fut (bien ou mal) enseignée jadis. Avec deux résultats importants: 1. jadis, j'ai cru comprendre qqch de ce qui m'était enseigné et j'ai adapté mon élocution en conséquence et 2. Ainsi adapté, je me suis fait comprendre de mes contemporains jusqu'à aujourd'hui.

@None et ça va sans doute mieux en le disant: je n'ai pas non plus essayé d'expliquer à mes contemporains comment eux-mêmes prononcent le français. Je ne suis pas phonéticien du français, même amateur: juste pratiquant.

@None J'ai ajouté deux exemples beaucoup plus clairs du son auquel je fais référence. Vous n'entendez pas la différence ? J'entends une différence très nette.

Pour revenir à mon commentaire ci-dessus, c'est possible que deux i que tu entends soient une illusion causée par la différence phonétique entre les i en suédois et le i en français. Quant à moi, quand j'entends les mots travail, Versailles, etc., quelquefois j'entends le i anglais de ride, mais pas tout le temps.

@Peter Peut-être. Mais je ne suis pas suédois (et je ne le parle pas), et ce son est completement étranger pour moi, en fait je ne le sais pas prononcer. Mes langues natives sont le catalan, l'espagnol et l'italien, et dans ces troi langues nous avons uniquement une [i], et c'est exactement la même dans les troi. Ce son existe en français aussi, et en suédois, selon je l'entends, je crois que c'est le même que dans . Mais le son dans  est toute autre chose. Peut-être que c'est seulement une perception pas réale, mais ce serait une illusion très très convaincante...

@Anakhand: ok, je suis perplexe.

@Anakhand J'entends un très léger sifflement entre la dentale et le i, aux points chronométrés de la vidéo: dzire, phonétsique, partsie. Bien plus léger que le chuintement de l'ami kabyle décrit dans mon 1er commentaire. Ca peut aussi trahir un défaut de qualité de l'enregistrement numérique, qui donne une sorte de (très léger) grincement métallique en écho à la voix, spécialement sur les consonnes sifflantes.

@FrançoisJurain Je crois pas que c'est l'enregistrement, car je l'ai entendu aussi en personne en France, à la TV, et avec d'autres personnes; c'est pas un cas isolé. J'ai mis cette personne seulement parce c'était ce que j'avais en main. J'ai demandé aussi à un ami suédois et il entend la différence aussi. C'est vraiment bizarre que d'autres francophones ne l'entendent pas, étant eux-mêmes qui le produisent...

Je n'entends pas de différence... peut-être que certains sont plus sensibles que d'autres, ou ont de meilleures oreilles.

@Anakhand voici une vidéo où le mot poutine revient souvent, prononcé à la québecoise, que j'entends "poutsiéne" (la sifflante très peu marquée; le é très fermé, à peine moins que l'i) De même "petsiéte" pour petite. Est-ce le même son que tu entends dans la vidéo d'Elisa? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mf2y0TYQFM4

@Anakhand sur cette caractéristique du québecois: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32583/affrication-des-dentales-au-qu%C3%A9bec

@Anakhand et de la banlieue parisienne: https://www.rts.ch/info/sciences-tech/2024/article/l-affrication-ce-tic-de-langage-passe-des-armaillis-aux-jeunes-des-banlieues-28387121.html

L'affrication n'a rien à voir avec la prononciation d'une voyelle.

@François Là je sents un troisième son, plus ouvert: le [ɪ] de l'API . C'est le même que dans le mot anglais  ou .

Par contre, dans la même vidéo j'entends le son aquel je fais référence ci-dessus dans le mots aujourd'hui et dire, bien que moins marqué. (Et aussi le [i] normale dans centième, par example.)

Si je m'en tiens à la phonologie du suédois, le "i" de sil est un [i:] alors que celui de sill est un [ɪ].
Ce dernier est proche du "i" de l'anglais bit ou kit alors que le premier serait plus proche du "i" de l'anglais beet.
Nos oreilles francophones ne font guère de différence mais la confusion entre les deux, ou plus précisément, l'utilisation de [i] là ou [ɪ] est attendu, est typique de l'accent français.
Il n'est donc pas du tout impossible que des variations de "i" imperceptibles à nos oreilles soient interprétées comme suffisantes pour distinguer ces deux voyelles par un locuteur dont la langue dispose de ces deux voyelles.
Le phonéticien anglais Geoff Lindsey nous conseille d'utiliser la voyelle de chez plutôt qu'un "i" pour nous rapprocher de la voyelle [ɪ] attendue en anglais : YouTube.

Judging from online pronunciations, the Swedish [ɪ] in sil is not an English [ɪ];  to me, Swedish sil sounds a little more like English seal than English sill.

@Peter Exactly. What confuses me is that I thought IPA phones were meant to be absolute, to mean the same across languages, but they don't seem to have done a good use of this. I hear three distinct sounds, from more closed to more open: the /i/ in  (Swedish), the /i/ in  (Swedish) or  (English) or  (Catalan, Spanish, Italian, French), and the /ɪ/ in ,  (English). I would transcribe the last two as [i] and [ɪ] respectively, and I would use a different symbol altogether for the first one. [...]

[...] However, for some reason, since only the first two sounds appear in Swedish, they decided to transcribe them as [i] and [ɪ] respectively. This maintains the relative closedness between the two sounds but is inconsistent across languages, which is a pity I think. You can hear here or at any other IPA chart with audio that the IPA [i] is very distinct from the sound in , and that it sounds instead like , which in turn is trascribed as [ɪ]. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_phonology

Anakhand: IPA phonemes may originally have been meant to be absolute, but in practice they are not.

Vu la perplexité des personnes interrogées par l'OP et la quantité de commentaires, il est probable que sa question intiale est généralement comprise de travers:

il n'existe dans la phonétique française qu'un seul (allo)phone pour
le phonème /i/, à savoir le [i] de l'API. Mais parfois j'entends un
autre allophone, plus fermé, le plus souvent à la fin de certains
mots.

Les personnes interrogées écoutent les passages indiqués et, par conséquent, entendent très exactement ce qu'elles s'attendaient à entendre.
Cette situation n'est pas celle de l'OP, qui a reçu à brûle-pourpoint un son qu'il n'attendait pas: d'où son post. Lorsqu'il rejoue les exemples qu'il a choisis, il écoute la prononciation et entend très exactement ce à quoi il s'attendait: le souvenir qu'il garde de la première audition. Pourtant, celle-ci était spéciale en ce qu'il  écoutait alors le message émis et non sa prononciation.
Mon hypothèse est que le facteur de surprise n'est pas la voyelle i elle-même, c'est la dentale partiellement assibilée qui précède immédiatement. À l'appui, le fait que tous les exemples indiqués sont relatifs à l'émission d'une syllabe ti ou di.
Ajouté en complément:
Ainsi que dui, dans des commentaires.
Dans les exemples indiqués par l'OP, je n'entends pas comme lui

un autre allophone, plus fermé

que notre [i] standard. Par contre j'entends dans tous ces exemples une assibilation partielle, à laquelle il ne paraît pas sensible. J'entends la syllabe complète prononcée t(s)i ou d(z)i; les parenthèses dénotant que la sifflante est anormalement peu marquée, relativement à p. ex. Tsigane ou Dzoungarie. Je propose donc l'interprétation suivante:
Dans les exemples retenus par l'OP, le locuteur ferme moins les lèvres pour prononcer les dentales que pour prononcer le i qui suit.
Dans cette hypothèse, l'OP perçoit un é bref et très fermé entre le t et le i: le mot petit est perçu pet(sé)i ou pet(é)i, selon que le locuteur réalise ou non la sifflante. L'impression subjective est d'un i plus fermé que la normale, alors qu'en fait il est plus ouvert en début de syllabe et rejoint finalement la normale.
P. S. Merci à @None de nous le rappeler: la réalité décrite par les phonéticiens existe autant que celle vécue par les locuteurs.
P. P. S. Quoique dans des espaces-temps séparés.

Si tu entends une différence, c'est certainement qu'il y en a une, mais pour moi c'est très subtil. Deux phénomènes peuvent expliquer ces légères variations :

L'affrication de la consonne précédant le "i" (dans les exemples 1, 3 et 4),  comme le note François Jurain, peut avoir pour effet de distordre ou rallonger légèrement celui-ci.
Le fait que le la syllabe contenant le "i" soit en fin de mot dans les exemples 1 et 2 en fait un moment adéquat pour "laisser traîner" la voyelle en cas d'hésitation dans le propos voire d'effet volontaire de suspense narratif.

Mais comme dans toutes les langues, de multiples  facteurs liés au locuteur, au contexte... influent sur la prononciation. Un homme politique qui fait un long discours lancinant pourra étirer ses "i" alors qu'une personne en colère va les raccourcir pour plus d'impact. Pour autant, les linguistes me reprendront si je dis des bêtises, mais on ne va pas représenter ces cas différemment en phonétique et ce ne sont pas des phonèmes distincts.
Ce que tu pointes dans les vidéos est encore beaucoup plus léger que ces exemples et me parait bien en-dessous d'un seuil de variabilité significatif pour en tirer une règle générale sur le plan de la phonétique.

Je suis d'accord que c'est pas une différence phonémique en français, mais je crois que ce sont des sons suffisamment différents pour les considérer des phones différents, en tant que ces deux phones forment deux phonèmes distincts en suédois par example et donc ils ne peuvent pas être (presque) le même son, par définition. Et donc je ne suis pas d'accord que c'est une difference plus légère que les examples que vous méntionnez. J'entends une difference de timbre du son, pas de durée: l'un plus simple et pur (la [i] normale), l'autre avec plus d'harmoniques, plus "complexe", je sais pas...

Peut-être que c'est une question très subjetive si on l'entend ou non. J'ai n'ai pas les moyens, mais si on ferait un spéctrogramme de ces deux sons, je mettrai ma main au feu que on pourrait voire une différence des fréquences/harmoniques.

Mais le spectrogramme ne montrerait pas une différence aussi grande qu'entre sil et sill en Suédois. Ca arrive tout le temps que la prononciation de voyelles soit légèrement altérée par la proximité de tel ou tel son voisin chez certains locuteurs... Mais on pourrait aussi retrouver plein d'extraits sonores de discours où le mot "partie" est prononcé avec un [i] tout à fait standard, voire plus proche du [i:]. Que conclure ?

"Mais on pourrait aussi retrouver..." Oui, bien sûr, moi même je les prononce comme ça. "Que conclure ?" Que les deux sons existent en français. C'est seulement ça que je veux vérifier. C'est une question des sons eux-mêmes, les mots ne sont q'un exemple d'où les trouver. Je ne veux pas dire que ces mots se prononcent (ou bien moins se doivent prononcer) toujours comme ça.

(Et une fois accepté l'existence de cette différence, une question secondaire serait de déterminer quelle est la difference articulative, "en bouche", de ces sons, pour savoir comment les transcrire (et réproduire!) correctement. En fait, une des raisons pour faire ce post est d'essayer de savoir comment réproduire ce son moi même!)

Mais tous les sons qui se trouvent entre deux phonèmes "officiels" existent en français parlé... c'est un continuum, pas une série de valeurs discrètes.

Yes of course, but that's a bit of a strawman, I think you know exactly what I mean... Let me be more precise: by "the difference existing", I mean that there is a continuum of sounds occurring in real French speech that cluster around two different points, this clustering being clear enough to justify the use of two "discrete" phones. Otherwise we might as well forget the whole concepts of phones and the IPA and just stick to phonemes within a single language...

It's not a strawman, you said yourself that "the sound exists" is exactly what you want to prove. We seem to disagree, for me the clustering is not clear enough to give the sound its own category. Anyway, we would need a real phonetician for a rigorous answer (which probably won't happen here).

It was a strawman in your interpretation of my use of "exists", but in any case, it seems I have now clarified what I meant. Yes, we disagree on the answer, but to be honest I'm already glad we now agree on what the question is in the first place haha :) And also agree with your last observation.
